# How can connect to modem router in java code

Tags: java, android

I want to connect to my router with ip address 192.168.1.1 in android and java code. I have username and password of my modem too. how can i connect to my modem in java code?
my username and password is admin.any body can help me?

Comment: If you consider the answer good, please set it as correct :)

Comment: that is good but it's have 10MB and this is make a big size apk for my application. do you have any other idea?

Comment: Try the version from sourceforge: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.htmlunit/htmlunit/2.14 ,it has 1.4MB  I assume you are using Maven for dependency management?

Comment: Edited my answer, apparently JSoup is a better alternative for filling forms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) a try. It's a non-gui browser and among other features, you can fill out forms and such.

**EDIT:** Lookng around and I see that a better alternative for android is [JSoup](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup), which is considerably smaller than the `HtmlUnit` package.

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example/)'s a tutorial as well.